# Pyspark pendant of Pandas' Rolling given time interval

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, rolling-sum

Is there an pendant for this Pandas functionality in Pyspark?

```
pandasDataFrame.rolling('2s', min_periods=1).sum()
```

where the columns in question have timestamps like this

```
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3.0
:
```

(documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html )

:

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window

Comment: perfect, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks, Steven! Cannot mark it as the correct answer however, as it is just a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window) function in spark.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn(
    "window",
    F.window("tmst", "2 secondes")
)
```